# Active Storage _blob partial not being respected or loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7, actiontext

I am trying to edit `app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb`, the partial file created when installing active_storage which allows you to customise how blobs appear inside action_text output.

On other projects, this has worked without issue, on a new Rails 7 project it would appear that the partial added during install is being ignored, as such no edits are coming through.

I can see this by making a small text change (so not adding an HTML element which may get stripped).

For example, I've added "this is a test" in a few places, this does not show:

`app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb`:

```
<figure class="attachment attachment--<%= blob.representable? ? "preview" : "file" %> attachment--<%= blob.filename.extension %>">
  <% if blob.representable? %>
    <%= image_tag blob.representation(resize_to_limit: local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ]) %>
  <% end %>

  <figcaption class="attachment__caption">
    <% if caption = blob.try(:caption) %>
      <%= caption %>
      this is a test
    <% else %>
      <span class="attachment__name"><%= blob.filename %></span>
      <span>this is a test</span>
      <span class="attachment__size"><%= number_to_human_size blob.byte_size %></span>
    <% end %>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

In other projects, when you view the log output in development it will correctly say "rendered app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb", on this project it doesn't.

File uploads work via actiontext, and rendering the file works by way of the built-in partial, but I can't get the customisable version to be viewed at all.

This is happening on both development and production environments, so I don't think it is anything like a weird eager loading/caching issue.

Does anyone have any ideas as to where I could start looking to debug this further?

- rails: 7.0.2.3

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. Did you end up figuring out why changes to _blob.html.erb are not working?

Comment: @sq1020 unfortunately not

Comment: FWIW. I had the same problem until I noticed the `has_rich_text :content` line in my model, while in fact the ActionText field in my model was called "body" and not "content". Changed it to `has_rich_text :body` and now the partial is picked up.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time to debug this until I realized that what I thought was a blob attachment turned out to be a "remote image" attachment. (Seen in [source code for example here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actiontext/lib/action_text/attachable.rb#L29)).

While this was a weird glitch in our test data, Rails renders [`views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actiontext/app/views/action_text/attachables/_remote_image.html.erb) in this case instead.